# Unable to access my website outside local network

Tags: iis-6

I'm hosting my website on IIS. I am able to access the website via localhost and the system's IP address, but I'm unable to access it outside of my local network. I am able to remotely control that machine using mstsc.

I believe that the firewall is completely disabled. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

If your external IP address is different from your machines' intranet IP address, what you need is port forwarding configured in your router. I.e. external requests coming to ports 80 (HTTP) and port 443 (HTTPS) should be re-routed to your IIS PC.

Disregard port 443, if your web site is not using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

Comment: My public ip is http://117.218.212.17/EV/Pages/DataEntry.aspx, my local ip is 192.168.1.105(where my iis is runing), do i need to keep static ip

Comment: It depends. Some learned to live without static IPs by using external dynamic DNS services. Kind of annoying, but works.